# Questions about multiple booleans in Java

Tags: java

Why am I getting `Multiple markers at this line

```
- Syntax error on token "=", != 
 expected` error? I am coding in Eclipse.
```

Is there anything wrong with my code?

`a_Exists`, `l_Exists`, `v_Exists` and `all_Exits` are boolean

```
if(a_Exists=false && l_Exists=false && v_Exists=false)
{
    all_Exists = false;
}
```

Comment: Well. You just got a SWARM of answers. Enjoy :)

Comment: lol idk i have to accept whose answer -.- I just voted up

Answer (score 4):

Three things are wrong:

1. You are using assignments instead of comparisons,
2. It is more common to use `!x` instead of `x==false` with `boolean`s:
3. The `if` statement is unnecessary - you can do it in a single expression.

Here is how:

```
all_Exists = a_Exists && l_Exists && v_Exists;
```

Comment: What if he doesn't want all_Exists to be true if the right side evaluates to true?

Comment: @Tyler My guess is that he wouldn't call it `all_Exists` then.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `==` for comparisons, however, as we're using booleans here you can get away with

```
if(!a_Exists && !l_Exists && !v_Exists)
{
    all_Exists = false;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain why i have to put 2 `==`?
//This work fine
if(assets_Exists=true)
{
   
}

Comment: Don't! write `!a_Exists` instead, using `==` when comparing `boolean`s is a very bad practice.

Comment: @Jeremy That **doesn't** work always fine in the case you've mentioned. `if(assets_Exists=true)` is **always** `true`. Java decided that `=` is the assigning operator and `==` is for comparing..

Answer (score 3):

`a_Exists=false` assigns `false` value to `a_Exists`.

You can use `==` to compare or better use:

```
if(!a_Exists && !l_Exists && !v_Exists)
```

Answer (score 3):

You're not comparing values, but rather trying to assign new.. It should be something like:

```
if(a_Exists == false && l_Exists == false && v_Exists == false)
{
    all_Exists = false;
}
```

Single `=` assigns
Double `==` compares

You could also use the *not*-operator `!` instead of comparing with false, like this:

```
if(!a_Exists && !l_Exists && !v_Exists)
{
    all_Exists = false;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
if(a_Exists=false && l_Exists=false && v_Exists=false)
```

This is **always** false, because you are assigning `false` to `a_Exists`, and since the assignee will get the assigned value, the expression will be like:

```
if(false && l_Exists=false && v_Exists=false)
```

Due to [Short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation), the next two conditions won't be reached.

That's why it's HIGHLY recommended (and a must) to write:

`if(!myBoolean)`

Instead of:

`if(myBoolean == false)`

Answer (score 3):

In Java, and other languages, `=` denotes an assignment. You want to do a comparison, and that is achieved by using `==` (double equals).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to combine assignment with if-check, you should take expression in brackets, but this is not a good style:

```
boolean a_Exists , l_Exists, v_Exists, all_Exists;
if((a_Exists = true) && (l_Exists = false) && (v_Exists = true)){
    all_Exists = true;
}
```